# jQuery thead object can't append tr object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, append

My problem is: I can not append `tr` objects to `thead` object, but `tfoot` works correctly.

There is no error, warning or anything, just in the resulting html code the `thead` tag will be empty.

```js
var tableObj = $("<table />");
var theadObj = $("<thead />");
var tbodyObj = $("<tbody />");
var tfootObj = $("<tfoot />");

var trObj = $("<tr />");
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName1"));
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName2"));
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName3"));

var trObj2 = $("<tr />");
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue1"));
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue2"));
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue3"));

theadObj.append(trObj); //as you can see in the result, the <thead> will be empty, why?
//theadObj.html('<tr>' + trObj.html() + '</tr>'); //but this works (it so ugly)
            
tfootObj.append(trObj);

tbodyObj.append(trObj2);

tableObj.append(theadObj);
tableObj.append(tbodyObj);
tableObj.append(tfootObj);

$("#test").append(tableObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

If anybody has any idea, please share with me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you can append it to the `thead` but your problem here is that you are appending the same `object`, to the `thead` then to the `tfoot`, so the second `apppend` operation is omitting the first one and the object is moved to the `tfoot`, that's why you only see it appended to the **tfoot**.

Here's a snippet showing it appended to the `thead` only (I commented the code that appends it to the `tfoot`).

```js
var tableObj = $("<table />");
var theadObj = $("<thead />");
var tbodyObj = $("<tbody />");
var tfootObj = $("<tfoot />");

var trObj = $("<tr />");
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName1"));
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName2"));
trObj.append($("<th />").html("colName3"));

var trObj2 = $("<tr />");
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue1"));
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue2"));
trObj2.append($("<td />").html("colValue3"));

theadObj.append(trObj); //as you can see in the result, the <thead> will be empty, why?
//theadObj.html('<tr>' + trObj.html() + '</tr>'); //but this works (it so ugly)
            
//tfootObj.append(trObj);

tbodyObj.append(trObj2);

tableObj.append(theadObj);
tableObj.append(tbodyObj);
tableObj.append(tfootObj);

$("#test").append(tableObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

So in conclusion, an object can only be appended to a single element.

Comment: @connexo Yes I just wanted to say that it's omitting the first append operation.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! For anybody: i duplicate the trObj with jquery.clone() function, and it worked.

Comment: @mhanol Yes that's it, you need to treat different objects :) Glad it helps.